# MinIO docker-compose AccessDenied

Tags: python, minio

My MinIO container
When I try to create the MinIO bucket, I have an error:

```
S3 operation failed; code: AccessDenied, message: Access denied
```

I'm creating the bucket with Python minio:

```py
minio_client = minio.Minio(endpoint=os.getenv("MINIO_HOST"), secure=False)

if not minio_client.bucket_exists("bucket1"):
    minio_client.make_bucket("bucket1")
```

```yaml
minio:
  image: minio/minio
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    - "9001:9001"
  volumes:
    - /.minio_storage:/data
  environment:
    MINIO_ROOT_USER: admin
    MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  command: server --address 0.0.0.0:9000 --console-address ":9001" /data
  restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: I dont see you using the user and password anywhere in your pythoncode.

Comment: Take a look at the [example code in the documentation](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/python/minio-py.html#file-uploader-py) for how to provide your username and password (aka access key and secret key).